# Easy Tensor Notation: What is $\partial_\mu\partial^\nu x_\nu$

Tags: notation, tensors

Part of a far larger piece of work...

I know it should simplify $\partial^\nu x_\nu\partial_\mu$ but I don't know how. Similarly, does it change for the reverse?

In other words I want to simplify:

1. $\partial_\mu\partial^\nu x_\nu$
2. $\partial^\nu x_\nu\partial_\mu$

Comment: You need to be clearer about what acts on what. For example, does your first operator act like $\partial^\nu (x_\nu \partial_\mu f)$ or $((\partial^\nu x_\nu) \partial_\mu) f$?

Comment: The latter: Standard operators. Apologies again for using sloppy physicist notation. @Sharkos I looked up your website and saw you're doing HEP: I'm using one of the Killing vector fields for invariant CFT symmetry

Comment: There is nothing more or less standard about either expression, even in the physics literature. It would be usual to state "where operators act only on the expressions immediately to their right" or "where operators act on everything to their right".

Comment: got the answer. I'll post it in a sec